# Switching focus to a hidden textbox on click

Tags: javascript

I have a button in my nav bar that switches the visibility of my search bar from hidden to display and would like the cursor to be switched to the textbox on click. I read some old answers on here that suggested that it is not possible to switch focus to a hidden element, but was wondering whether it would be possible to add a delay between the two functions so that when the browser attempts to switch focus to the textbox it is no longer hidden.

eg -> click to make the search bar visible->100ms delay->switch focus to the textbar.

I'm aware that switching the position or opacity of the searchbar could yield the same results, but doing so seems to screw up the positioning of other elements on the page and so am keen to find a solution using my current code if possible. Obviously, any help is greatly appreciated.

My onclick function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showMe() {
   var foo = document.getElementById('searchbar');

   if(foo.style.display == '' || foo.style.display == 'none'){
        foo.style.display = 'block';
   }
   else {
        foo.style.display = 'none';
   }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function showMe() {
   var foo = document.getElementById('searchbar');

   if(foo.style.display == '' || foo.style.display == 'none'){
        foo.style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout( () => foo.focus(), 500);
   }
   else {
        foo.style.display = 'none';
   }
}

</script>
```

Comment: This looks like it might be along the right lines, but the element that needs to be focused on is different to the element that I want to switch focus to which I'm assuming is what is preventing this from working. ('searchbar' is a div that contains the textbox rather than the id of the textbox itself).

Comment: This seemed to do the trick. Many thanks!

````
<script type="text/javascript">

function showMe() {
   var foo = document.getElementById('searchbar');
   var bar = document.getElementById('resizedtextbox')

   if(foo.style.display == '' || foo.style.display == 'none'){
        foo.style.display = 'block';
        setTimeout( () => bar.focus(), 100);
   }
   else {
        foo.style.display = 'none';
   }
}

</script>
````